# Помогите разобраться с сотавлением запроса

Tags: javascript, http, request, xmlhttprequest

Есть сайт [naurok.ua](http://naurok.ua). На странице [/student/tests](https://naurok.ua/student/tests) есть форма для отправки данных. Для того, что б узнать какие данные и в каком формате отправляются в запросе я ввёл следующие данные и нажал "присоединиться":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откудого появляется **JoinForm[name]** и **JoinForm[gamecode]** я понимаю, а откудого **_csrf** - нет. Скорее всего она генерируется в js скрипте либо храниться как константа, полученная с сервера. Для тех, кто работает в вебе, я думаю, кто-нибудь да сталкивался с этим полем, подскажите пожалуйста, как вы думаете, где оно есть.

Comment: Это сгенерированный токен:https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens

Comment: посмотрите `html` код, там скорее всего есть скрытое поле с этим значением

Comment: Таки да, он храниться в html, причём дважды. Огромное спасибо